# Add close button to mobile nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following site here: http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/ and the issue is in mobile mode when the hamburger menu appears.

You will see I have positioned the hamburger icon in the centre of the header strip, but this presents a problem as when I open the mobile menu, the hamburger icon slides out and I can't click it to close the menu again.

My initial thought was to have the menu slide in from the top, butI wasn't sure how to achieve that, so my next thought is to simply have a 'close' X or even the word CLOSE somewhere in the mobile menu which will enable the menu to slide back out...

From what I can see, my CSS is here:

```
/* NAVIGATION
   ========================================================================== */
/* Body Class - slides the webpage to the left to allow the nav menu to appear */
.page-slide {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.page-slide-out {
    right: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    /*top: 0;*/
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 68.75em) {
    .page-slide-out {
        right: 350px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 68.75em) {
    .page-slide-out {
        right: 0;
    }
}

#nav__menu-pos {
    /*float: right;*/
}

.nav {
    /* Hamburger Icon */
    /* Navigation Menu */
    /* Navigation links */
}
.nav__menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .nav__menu {
        margin-top: 32px;
    }
}

.nav__menu_line {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
@media (min-width: 68.75em) {
    .nav__menu {
        display: none;
        margin-top: 32px;
    }
}

.nav__bar {
    margin-left: 205px;
    background-color: #262625;
    position: fixed;
    color: #FFF;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.nav__bar.nav--pushed-open {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.nav__bar ul {
    margin-top: 6%;
}
@media (min-width: 68.75em) {
    .nav__bar ul {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
.menu-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    /* Navigation Menu Media Query */
}
.menu-item a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8% 0;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: #A2C663;
}
@media (min-width: 68.75em) {
    .menu-item {
        float: left;
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .menu-item a {
        padding: 39px 15px 0 15px;
    }
    .menu-item:hover {
        border-color: #f4f18e;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1099px) {
    .nav__bar {
        max-width: 350px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 68.75em) {
    .nav__bar {
        position: static;
        background-color: transparent;
        width: auto;
        transform: translateX(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transition: all 0s;
    }
}
```

So, I guess I would either like to learn how to slide it in from the top OR how to add a close button inside the menu when open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the close button is actually there, it just gets shifted out of the page. So if you change its positioning a bit, you can make it come back into view again. Try this:

```
.nav__menu--is-toggled {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I'd say this is the most low-effort solution to your problem.

Comment: Chosen this for now, until I have some free time try other options :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what it seems the only time that side navigation is seen is when you're using a smaller view. You could just simply add the close icon/text in here with a few extra CSS styles

Since the menu isn't visible when it's not open, You do not need to add the close button when it's open, but instead, you can always have it there.

Create another list element:

```
<li id="menu-item-566" class="mobile-close menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-566"><a href="http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/contact-us/">Close</a></li>
```

And give the styles:

```
.mobile-close {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -33px; /* (-50% width) */
    /* Anything else */
}
```

Also! Greetings from Leicester too! :)

Comment: Thanks @ConorReidd Greetings from Leicester! Small world :) Do you work... freelance... ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not :)

Comment: Are you looking to be a developer? they might be few and far between, but I sometimes have jobs that I need help with (save me jumping on Stack!!) - Would you want to email me some details, experience, skills etc so I can put you on file? No promises of work straight the way but I'd like to have a developer on file...

Comment: If so, email me here: shaun@loveidee.com also, if you set up a profile here: http://seedcreativenetwork.co.uk -  It's a collection of creatives / web designer etc in Leicester - let me know when you have done so and we might be able to promote it in our network...

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things:
1. do not touch the main website at all and make that menu just appear on top
2. then make that navigation appear little lower then Your header row, I would say top: 76px would be fine
And one more thing - some times Your navigation will not fit on screen so You better make it scroll in that case and set overflow: scroll;

In code It should look like this:

```
 /*style.css @1319 */
.nav__bar.nav--pushed-open {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
   -ms-transform: translateX(0);
   transform: translateX(0);
   top: 76px;
   overflow: scroll; /* this is for smaller screens */
}

/* style.css @1238 */
.page-slide-out {
   /*
   .....

   comment out all stuff 
   or make sure that this class is not applied 
   on a body when toggling navigation
  */
}
```